# Deshabilitar una función JQUERY si los INPUT vienen vacíos, y habilitar función viceversa

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente problema. Necesito 'validar' esta pequeña parte del formulario, si viene vacío que el `<a href="#" id="masfilas">AGREGAR</a>` no ejecute la función de agregar más filas si estos input estan vacios:

```js
//totalizar tabla resumen  
$(function() {/*ESTA FUNCIÓN QUIERO DESHABILITAR SI VIENEN LOS INPUT VACIOS*/
$("#masfilas").click(function() {
var add = 0;
$(".imp").each(function() {
add += Number($(this).val());
});
$("#totalidad").text(add);
});
});
//Agrega filas a mytable
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#masfilas").click(function(){
        var qty = $("#qty");
  var upc = $("#upc");
  var nomprod = $("#nomprod");
  var precio = $("#precio");
  var discount = $("#discount");
  var impuestos = $("#impuestos");
  var total = $("#total");
        $("#mytable").append('<tr><td align="center" class="nuevalinea">' + qty.val() + '</td><td align="center" class="nuevalinea">' + upc.val() + '</td><td class="nuevalinea">' + nomprod.val() + '</td><td class="nuevalinea">' + precio.val() + '</td><td class="nuevalinea">' + discount.val() + '</td><td id="taxes1" class="nuevalinea">' + impuestos.val() + '</td><td id="total1" class="nuevalinea">' + total.val() + '</td><td align="center" class="nuevalinea"><a href="#" class="delete" title="Eliminar línea" style="cursor:pointer;">ELIMINAR</a></td></tr>');
        $('.delete').off().click(function(e) {
            $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();
        });
  });
});
//enviar los valores a tabla resumen
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#masfilas").click(function(){
        var qty = $("#qty");
  var upc = $("#upc");
  var nomprod = $("#nomprod");
  var precio = $("#precio");
  var discount = $("#discount");
  var impuestos = $("#impuestos");
  var total = $("#total");
        $("#subtotal").append('<tr><td>' + total.val() + '</td></tr>');
        $("#descuentos").append('<tr><td>' + discount.val() + '</td></tr>');
  $("#taxes").append('<tr><td>' + impuestos.val() + '</td></tr>');
  $('.delete').off().click(function(e) {
            $("#subtotal").remove();
   $("#descuentos").remove();
   $("#taxes").remove();
   $("#totalidad").remove();
   $(".nuevalinea").remove();
        });
  qty.val("");
  upc.val("");
  nomprod.val("");
  precio.val("");
  discount.val("");
  impuestos.val("");
  total.val("");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="70%" align="center">
 <tr>
     <td colspan="8"><b>Agregar Artículos / Servicios:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Cantidad:</td>
        <td>Código:</td>
        <td>Nombre:</td>
        <td>Precio:</td>
        <td>Descuento (%):</td>
        <td>Impuesto:</td>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td>Opciones:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><!--SI ESTOS INPUT VIENEN VACIOS NO QUIERO QUE SE EJECUTE EL JQUERY DE #masfilas OSEA NO AGREGAR FILAS-->
     <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="quantity" size="5" title="Cantidad"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="upc" name="codigo" size="12" title="Código" placeholder="744105300000"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="nomprod" name="nombre" size="23" title="Nombre"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="precio" name="price" size="10" title="Precio del producto" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" size="15" title="Descuento" placeholder="0.00%"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="impuestos" class="imp" name="impuestoivi" size="15" title="Impuesto de Ventas" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="total" class="imp" name="totalizar" size="15" title="Total de Línea" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
        <td><a href="#" title="Agregar línea" id="masfilas" class="add_form_field" style="cursor:pointer;">AGREGAR</a></td><!--SI VIENE VACIO LOS INPUT NO EJECUTAR FUNCION-->
    </tr>
</table>

<table width="70%" align="center" border="1" id="mytable" class="table-bordered table-striped">
 <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
     <td width="70%" align="left" colspan="8"><b>RESUMEN DEL CARRITO</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td width="3%">Cantidad:</td>
        <td width="10%">Código:</td>
        <td width="13%">Nombre:</td>
        <td width="5%">Precio:</td>
        <td width="9%">Descuento (%):</td>
        <td width="10%">Impuesto:</td>
        <td width="10%">Total:</td>
        <td colspan="2" width="10%">Opciones:</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table name="resumen" width="20%" align="left" border="1">
 <tr>
     <td>Subtotal</td>
        <td>CRC.<span id="subtotal"></span>.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>- Descuento</td>
        <td>CRC.<span id="descuentos"></span>.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Impuesto</td>
        <td>CRC.<span id="taxes"></span>.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Venta Total</td>
        <td>CRC.<span id="totalidad"></span>.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Porque tienes dos handlers?  En uno solo podrias hacer todo lo que necesitas

Comment: Revisa primeramente el javascript, `$(function() {}` y `$(document).ready(function() {}` básicamente hacen lo mismo, con solo que tengas un `$(document).ready(function() {}` es suficiente, así como esta el código es bastante "incomodo" ofrecer una ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Varias cosas a tener en cuenta de tu código:

1. Haz sólo una llamada a `$(function(){});`

A partir de jQuery 3.0 se recomienda utilizar esta sintaxis en vez de `$(document).ready(handler)`

> jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the
>   DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $( handler )
> $( document ).ready( handler )
> $( "document" ).ready( handler )
> $( "img" ).ready( handler )
> $().ready( handler )
> ```
>
> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other
>   syntaxes still work but are deprecated. This is because the selection
>   has no bearing on the behavior of the .ready() method, which is
>   inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's
>   behavior.

Este método lo que hace es esperar a que el DOM se haya cargado y entonces ejecutar la función indicada. En tu código la estás llamando 3 veces, lo cual no tiene sentido (salvo raras excepciones)

2. Haz sólo una llamada al manejador de click

Lo mismo pasa aquí. No tiene sentido que hagas tres llamadas a `$("#masfilas").click(function () {});` ya que con una te basta para definir el comportamiento deseado en el click.

3. Validación de elementos vacíos

Para validar si tienes elementos vacíos antes de insertar un registro puedes hacer un simple `if` comprobando los valores introducidos (con un `$.trim` para evitar los espacios en blanco) y mostrando un aviso o, si quieres algo más elaborado, puedes mirar plugins de validación como [este](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Te dejo tu código más resumido y con la validación:

```js
$(function () {

    $("#masfilas").click(function () {

        var qty = $("#qty");
        var upc = $("#upc");
        var nomprod = $("#nomprod");
        var precio = $("#precio");
        var discount = $("#discount");
        var impuestos = $("#impuestos");
        var total = $("#total");

        if ($.trim(qty.val()) == "" || $.trim(upc.val()) == "" || $.trim(nomprod.val()) == "" || $.trim(precio.val()) == "" || $.trim(impuestos.val()) == "" || $.trim(qty.val()) == "" || $.trim(discount.val()) == "" || $.trim(total.val()) == "") {
            alert("No se pueden insertar valores vacíos");
        }
        else {
            //Calculamos totalidad
            var add = 0;
            $(".imp").each(function () {
                add += Number($(this).val());
            });
            $("#totalidad").text(add);

            //Agrega filas a mytable
            $("#mytable").append('<tr><td align="center" class="nuevalinea">' + qty.val() + '</td><td align="center" class="nuevalinea">' + upc.val() + '</td><td class="nuevalinea">' + nomprod.val() + '</td><td class="nuevalinea">' + precio.val() + '</td><td class="nuevalinea">' + discount.val() + '</td><td id="taxes1" class="nuevalinea">' + impuestos.val() + '</td><td id="total1" class="nuevalinea">' + total.val() + '</td><td align="center" class="nuevalinea"><a href="#" class="delete" title="Eliminar línea" style="cursor:pointer;">ELIMINAR</a></td></tr>');
            $('.delete').off().click(function (e) {
                $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove();
            });

            //enviar los valores a tabla resumen
            $("#subtotal").append('<tr><td>' + total.val() + '</td></tr>');
            $("#descuentos").append('<tr><td>' + discount.val() + '</td></tr>');
            $("#taxes").append('<tr><td>' + impuestos.val() + '</td></tr>');
            $('.delete').off().click(function (e) {
                $("#subtotal").remove();
                $("#descuentos").remove();
                $("#taxes").remove();
                $("#totalidad").remove();
                $(".nuevalinea").remove();
            });

    qty.val("");
 upc.val("");
 nomprod.val("");
 precio.val("");
 discount.val("");
 impuestos.val("");
 total.val("");

        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="70%" align="center">
     <tr>
         <td colspan="8"><b>Agregar Artículos / Servicios:</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Cantidad:</td>
            <td>Código:</td>
            <td>Nombre:</td>
            <td>Precio:</td>
            <td>Descuento (%):</td>
            <td>Impuesto:</td>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>Opciones:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><!--SI ESTOS INPUT VIENEN VACIOS NO QUIERO QUE SE EJECUTE EL JQUERY DE #masfilas OSEA NO AGREGAR FILAS-->
         <td><input type="text" id="qty" name="quantity" size="5" title="Cantidad"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="upc" name="codigo" size="12" title="Código" placeholder="744105300000"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="nomprod" name="nombre" size="23" title="Nombre"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="precio" name="price" size="10" title="Precio del producto" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="discount" name="discount" size="15" title="Descuento" placeholder="0.00%"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="impuestos" class="imp" name="impuestoivi" size="15" title="Impuesto de Ventas" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="total" class="imp" name="totalizar" size="15" title="Total de Línea" placeholder="CRC. 0.00"/></td>
            <td><a href="#" title="Agregar línea" id="masfilas" class="add_form_field" style="cursor:pointer;">AGREGAR</a></td><!--SI VIENE VACIO LOS INPUT NO EJECUTAR FUNCION-->
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table width="70%" align="center" border="1" id="mytable" class="table-bordered table-striped">
     <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
         <td width="70%" align="left" colspan="8"><b>RESUMEN DEL CARRITO</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td width="3%">Cantidad:</td>
            <td width="10%">Código:</td>
            <td width="13%">Nombre:</td>
            <td width="5%">Precio:</td>
            <td width="9%">Descuento (%):</td>
            <td width="10%">Impuesto:</td>
            <td width="10%">Total:</td>
            <td colspan="2" width="10%">Opciones:</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table name="resumen" width="20%" align="left" border="1">
     <tr>
         <td>Subtotal</td>
            <td>CRC.<span id="subtotal"></span>.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>- Descuento</td>
            <td>CRC.<span id="descuentos"></span>.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Impuesto</td>
            <td>CRC.<span id="taxes"></span>.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Venta Total</td>
            <td>CRC.<span id="totalidad"></span>.00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```